# query formula combining cells

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to get a query formula to work in google spreadsheets. It is a very large data set (Formula is `=query(Sheet1!A3:EH)`). I am having trouble with it because after a few rows (and of course it taking forever to catch all the data), it starts to combine cells systematically. Sheet 1 will have the rows separated, but the sheet with the formula will have Sheet1!A3 combined with Sheet1!A4, also Sheet1!B3 combined with Sheet1!B4, almost like it merged them with a space in between. Any idea why this is happening? Is there a different formula I can use that is more reliable?

Answer (score 2):

The `query` formula combines header rows into one. If you do not provide the number of header rows as the 3rd argument of the formula, it guesses based on the data — and sometimes guesses wrong.

So, use `=query(Sheet1!A3:EH, "select ...", 0)` if your range A3:EH does not include header rows.